# Rotation of Linear Transformation in R2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix which represents a 45 degrees rotation counterclockwise: $$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$.

To find the matrices of Rot^4, why is this not the same matrix?

Thanks

Comment: Because $8*45=360$

Answer (score 0):

You matrix is 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\tfrac\pi4 & -\sin\tfrac\pi4 \\ \sin\tfrac\pi4& \cos\tfrac\pi4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then one can show (using induction and the cosime of the sum formula) that 
$$
A^k=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\tfrac{k\pi}4 & -\sin\tfrac{k\pi}4 \\ \sin\tfrac{k\pi}4& \cos\tfrac{k\pi}4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So to get $A^k=A$  we need $k\pi/4 = 2m\pi + \pi/4$, or $k=8m+1$. That is, you need to turn eight times to get $A$ again, so the first time you'll get $A$ again is $A^9$.

On a more intuitive way, your matrix is a rotation of $\pi/4$, and you need 8 more turns to get to the same point.